# white space under my footer need to remove it

Tags: php, html, css, footer

Hello please I need help with removing whitespace from all my website pages https://www.seowebanalyst.com

scroll down the footer you will see it. We just redesigned the site and do not know how this come to be as it was spotted by a visitor. Have tried all tricks previously stated on this site but none worked so am sharing a bit of the css code used for the css code that handles the page

```css
}
.footer {
 background:#333;
 padding:15px 0 10px
        overflow:hidden
}
.footer p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:15px;
 text-align:center
}
.footer p span, .footer p a {
 color:#fff;
```

Comment: Your provided link does not work.

Comment: try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle instead.

Comment: `so am sharing a bit of the css code` 1,000+ lines? Looks like you're sharing pretty much the entire css code. Have you looked into the problem at all?

Comment: just want to put in a few tricks I did for some pages that worked I placed <div class=clearfix></div> <div class=space40></div> above two </div> before the footer tag which worked to push the footer down..and everything looks good, but some pages do not work with this tactic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site footer error as been corrected with the following line into css

.footer {position: absolute;width: 100%;padding: 10px;}

.footer {margin: 0 auto -155px;}

didnot remove the former css footer line, just added this lines and it fixed all
no need to worry about using  
in code and not getting results with most pages.
the neww css line for footer resolved all headaches like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Footer tag after the `</body>` tag, And inside your CSS file .footer class change the `padding: 15px 0 10px overflow:hidden;` to `padding: 20px;` that should do the trick. -Arqetech

Comment: PS. Here's a tip inside your navbar change `.top-nav li {
float: left;
margin: 20px 15px 5px;
}` to this `.top-nav li {
float: left;
margin: 27px 15px 5px;
}` It's just a Friendly tip to make your nav look better aligned, Hope It helped you.

Comment: Your Welcome, Did you place It after the closing body tag? I tried It and It worked fine without any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

try adding to the footer

```
footer {position:relative;bottom:-14px}
```

Comment: all this lines to add to footer position:relative;bottom:-14px does not work. The only noticeable effect is that it now makes the height of the footer a bit smaller and makes font thinner. But space still remains.